# q.all() making duplicate ajax calls (Angularjs, $http, $q)

Tags: ajax, angularjs, q, deferred

I'm making two REST API calls to separate URL's using the same factory method.

**This is my current Angularjs code structure:**

```
angular.module('evtApp', [])

.controller('EventAppController', ['$scope', '$q', 'restApi', function($scope, $q, restApi) {

    // var ajaxCall_1 = restApi.fetchData(tweetUrl),
    //  ajaxCall_2 = restApi.fetchData(instaUrl);

    $q.all([restApi.fetchData(tweetUrl), restApi.fetchData(instaUrl)]).then(function() {
        // Save the the return data values to the respective scopes. 
        // $scope.tweetUrl = data;
        // $scope.instaUrl = data;
    });

}])

.factory('restApi', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {
        var q = $q.defer();
        return {
            fetchData: function(url) {
                $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    q.resolve(data);
                }).error(function(error) {
                    q.reject(error);
                });
                return q.promise;
            }
        };
    }])
```

When I look at the network request it shows that I've made 4 calls instead of

**Sample of the network calls:**

```
search?q=twitter,instagram,flicker&callback=angular.callbacks._3    
search?q=quotes:yes&callback=angular.callbacks._0
search?q=twitter,instagram,flicker&callback=angular.callbacks._1
search?q=quotes:yes&callback=angular.callbacks._2
```

What seems to be the problem? And, how can I get the return feeds and save the tweetURL call to $scope.tweetUrl and the instaUrl call to $scope.instaUrl.
I know jQuery `$.when(func1, func2).done(function(func1data, func2data){});`I get the values of the respective calls in the .done(). How can I do the same with the above code.

Comment: Can you include your .html as well? You probably have two EventAppController references and each will create a $scope. You can avoid the duplicate calls by moving it into a service or factory.

Comment: thanks Brad, I didn't realize that could be the problem, I did have 2 duplicate ng-controller with the same name. Thanks :). Anything on the 2nd part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second part, it's similar to the $.when call except it comes as an array:

```
$q.all([restApi.fetchData(tweetUrl), restApi.fetchData(instaUrl)]).then(function(data) {
    // Save the the return data values to the respective scopes. 
    $scope.tweetUrl = data[0];
    $scope.instaUrl = data[1];
});
```

Comment: That works! I saw the returned argument with the the returned array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

`$q.all ([ajaxCall_1, ajaxCall_2, restApi.fetchData (instaUrl)]).then(function () {//success call back});`

Basically you need to pass the promise object which you have created earlier.

Hope this could help you.Thanks.